# How do I remove the horizontal white space under each picture in this masonry.js layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling to remove the whitespace, or have it filled up. I thought the library was throwing in the `gutters` options in by default, but I tried setting it to `0` and it didn't achieve my goals.

I also tried to make my image fill the height of the container by using `height: 100%`. Also failed. I am almost line-by-line copying the html, css, and js from [this example here](http://demos.creative-punch.net/masonry-gallery/).

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var msnry = new Masonry( anchor, {
  percentPosition: true,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
});
}

const anchor = document.querySelector('.gallery');

//added a forward slash at the end of url
let randomURL = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/';

generateItems(15);

function generateItems(num) {
  for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    //this adds a number to the end of the url so that the same image isn't used repeatedly
    randomURL += num;
    //create nested elements and append to body
    const gridItem = document.createElement('div');
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', randomURL);
    gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
    gridItem.appendChild(img);
    anchor.appendChild(gridItem);
    console.log('added one');
  }
  
  console.log('Added HTML');
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-sizer, .grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
</div>
```

I am struggling to figure out why there is this whitespace, and how best to remove it for an edge-to-edge display.

I am pulling my images from unsplashed at random using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` or `display:block` to the `img` elements.

Working example (*modified*)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var msnry = new Masonry(anchor, {
    percentPosition: true,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  });
}

const anchor = document.querySelector('.gallery');

//added a forward slash at the end of url
let randomURL = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/';

generateItems(15);

function generateItems(num) {
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    //this adds a number to the end of the url so that the same image isn't used repeatedly
    randomURL += num;
    //create nested elements and append to body
    const gridItem = document.createElement('div');
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', randomURL);
    gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
    gridItem.appendChild(img);
    anchor.appendChild(gridItem);
    console.log('added one');
  }

  console.log('Added HTML');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @WonkasWilly just added your snippet in my answer (*modified with `display:block`*) and it works fine (*no gutters between images*).

Comment: So after you confirmed that it was working for you, I went into incognito mode and then tried reopened my Codepen (where I initially wrote this), and it worked fine! Do you have any idea why that might be...?

Comment: Actually, I realize why. It's because after I added in the `display: block` to the `img` tag, I didn't refresh the page, and the grid didn't re-initialize. Thank you for the fix! One last question...how did you know changing the `display` to `block` would fix the issue? I know that when an element is `display: block`, that it takes up as much room as possible horizontally, but I didn't know that it also does so vertically? Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I apologize for this barrage of messages; I guess my actual question is why didn't setting the `img` to `height: 100%` work in this case? Shouldn't the image have filled up the parent container, which is the `grid-item`?

Comment: Please disregard all of my questions and accept my thanks. I understand (after looking it up) that due to the fact that inline elements take the minimum amount of space possible, that turning it into a block allowed it to fill up the space correctly.